# Trigger python script on ec2 instance via lambda function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I currently have an ec2 set up that runs a script when booted up (I do this by calling the script in the user data field for the ec2 instance). Then I just send a command via lambda to start the ec2 instance and that causes the script to run. I would now like to run multiple scripts - ideally I'd have something like a lambda that starts the ec2 instance, then sends a notification to a second lambda when it is up and running to run various scripts on there before shutting it back down. How can I trigger a python script on a running ec2 instance via lambda?

Thanks

EDIT:

I believe I've found a quick solution. in the user data I point to a script like "startup.py"

in this script I can just import whatever series of scripts I want to execute. I just have to figure out the paths as the user data script is executes in a different directoy from /home/ec2-user/

Comment: Can you provide a higher-level explanation of what you are trying to achieve? For example, are you wanting Instance 1 to spawn another "worker" instance that will perform some work? There are probably better ways to do this (eg using SQS to queue-up instructions), but it would be helpful to have a better idea of what you are actually trying to accomplish. Feel free to Edit your question to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Scheduling SSH jobs** Trigger python script on ec2 instance.

This is the [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scheduling-ssh-jobs-using-aws-lambda/) that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

To run commands on EC2 instances from outside of them, you should consider using AWS Systems Manager [Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html). This allows you to run multiple, arbitrary commands across a number of instances that you choose (by instance Id, by resource group, or by tags). You can do this from the AWS console, CLI, or SDK.

Note that to use this, your instances need to be [configured correctly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/managed_instances.html).